# AlphaBeta with TT (MTD-f)

Tags: c++, algorithm, chess, minimax, alpha-beta-pruning

My question is about TTalphabeta. In MTD-f's paper (https://people.csail.mit.edu/plaat/mtdf.html) the implementation of alpha beta is quite different from other I found (https://homepages.cwi.nl/~paulk/theses/Carolus.pdf)

What is the difference between them?

My heuristic returns an int so no I got no decimals, should I take any special care?

My implementation know is:

```
template <class node, class transposition_table>
bound_and_action<node> alpha_beta_with_memory(node& root, depth depth,
        bound alpha, bound beta, transposition_table& table)
{


    auto value_in_hash = table.find(root);

    if (value_in_hash != table.end()
            && value_in_hash->second._depth > depth) { // Transposition table lookup

        auto bound_in_hash = value_in_hash->second;


        if ( bound_in_hash.lower_bound >= beta )
          return { bound_in_hash.lower_bound, root.get_action() };

        if ( bound_in_hash.upper_bound <= alpha )
          return { bound_in_hash.upper_bound, root.get_action() };


        alpha = std::max(alpha, bound_in_hash.lower_bound);
        beta = std::min(beta, bound_in_hash.upper_bound);
    }

    bound_and_action<node> ret;

    if ( depth == 0 || root.is_terminal() ) { // Leaf Node

      ret._bound = root.get_heuristic_value();
      ret._action = root.get_action();

    } else {

         list<node> children;
        root.get_children(children);

        if (root.is_max_node()) {

            ret._bound = INT_MIN;
            bound a = alpha; //Save original alpha

            for (auto child : children) {


                bound_and_action<node> possible_ret = alpha_beta_with_memory(child, depth - 1,
                                                      a, beta, table);

                if (possible_ret._bound == 1000) {
                    return {1000, root.get_action()};
                }

                if (possible_ret._bound > ret._bound ) {
                    ret._bound = possible_ret._bound;
                    ret._action = child.get_action();
                }

                a = std::max(a, ret._bound);

                if ( beta <= ret._bound ) {
                    break;    // beta cut-off
                }

            }

        } else { // if root is a min node.

            ret._bound = INT_MAX;
            bound b = beta; //Save original beta


            for (auto child : children) {


                bound_and_action <node> possible_ret = alpha_beta_with_memory(child, depth - 1,
                                                       alpha, b, table);

                if (possible_ret._bound == 1000) {
                    return {1000, root.get_action()};
                }

                if (possible_ret._bound < ret._bound) {
                    ret._bound = possible_ret._bound;
                    ret._action = child.get_action();
                }

                b = std::min(b, ret._bound);

                if ( ret._bound <= alpha ) {
                    break;    // alpha cut-off
                }

            }
        }
    }

    //
    //  ----- Transposition table storing of bounds.

    hash_struct& hash_value = table[root];

    if (hash_value._depth < depth) {
        // Fail low result implies an upper bound.
        if (ret._bound <= alpha) {
            hash_value.upper_bound = ret._bound;
        }
        // Found an accurate minimax value - will not occur if called with zero window.
        if ( ret._bound > alpha && ret._bound < beta){
          hash_value.lower_bound = ret._bound;
          hash_value.upper_bound = ret._bound;
        }

        // Fail high result implies a lower bound.
        if (ret._bound >= beta ) {
            hash_value.lower_bound = ret._bound;
        }

        hash_value._depth = depth;
        hash_value._action = ret._action;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

But it doesn't work as good as it should. 
Everything is fine if no TT is used so something in the use of it must be wrong.

Comment: The mtdf version tries to zoom in on the correct score by lots of re-searches with a null window. For it to work well, it has to store **both** an upper bound and a lower bound for each node in the table. Traditional alpha-beta just stores *either* an upper or a lower bound.

Comment: Using zero-window the value is never between alpha and beta so I don't need both bounds, that what sais the original paper.    /* Found an accurate minimax value - will not occur if called with zero window */ 
if g >  alpha and g < beta then
n.lowerbound := g; n.upperbound := g; store n.lowerbound, n.upperbound;

Comment: But you do. The zero windows will move back and forth all the time, so if you don't have two bounds in the TT, a lot of the lookups will not be useful.

Comment: I see, thank you for answering. Then the implementation in the second link is wrong?

Comment: I don't know really. If you are interested, you could check out the [publications of Don Dailey](https://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/Don+Dailey#Selected%20Publications). He has done some research on adapted versions of mtd-f.

Comment: I've already changed the algorith to have 2 bounds, if my heuristic is discrete do I have to change any comparation such as the one I said before?

Comment: I experimented with MTD(f) when Aske's thesis was new, about 20(!) years ago. I really don't remember details at that level. :-)